# Add a More button tableview xcode

Tags: uitableview

As in the apple store, I am looking to add a 'more' section to my tableview.

[image]

I have searched but I am not sure about how to explain what I am looking for. Can anyone help me with how to proceed to implement this?

I would like to have an expandable tableview for a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Link :- https://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/99011-uitableview-cell-size-increases-on-tap-of-uibutton-inside-it.html

Hope it help to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add more button in footer view of your tableview. So, it will show when user will scroll to bottom.

```
- (UIView *) createViewForTableFooter
{

    CGRect footerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 60);
    UIView *tableFooter = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect] autorelease];
    tableFooter.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIButton* verifyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [verifyButton setTitle:WNLocalizedString(@"More",@"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [verifyButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
    [verifyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(verifyBtnTapped:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    verifyButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [verifyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(44, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 88, 37)];

    }
    else{
        [verifyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, 37)];
    }
    [tableFooter addSubview:verifyButton];

    return tableFooter;
}

tableview.tableFooterView = [self createViewForTableFooter];
```